# Is it possible we create new column in Database by PHP and automatically show in HTML table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Maybe this is stupid, question. But I just wonder it's possible or not. I have a client and my client wants to make a new column from a table in Database MySQL via PHP (CI) framework, and then automatically show on the HTML table. So, when adding a new column via SQL command in PHP, it also automatically shows in the HTML table, but not manually by code. Is it possible to do that? Thanks, advance.

Comment: I think the answer to your slightly confusing question is YES

Comment: I am sorry @RiggsFolly for that, but thanks for your short answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch all the column names in a given database table with SQL using something like: `SHOW COLUMNS FROM <table_name_here>;`

If you reproduce the equivalent of that in your PHP project (using an ORM or a plain SQL query), you can iterate over the columns and use it to generate the HTML table. So if any new column is added to the table, it will be shown accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html#adding-a-column-to-a-table

```
$fields = array(
    'preferences' => array('type' => 'TEXT')
);
$this->dbforge->add_column('table_name', $fields);
// Executes: ALTER TABLE table_name ADD preferences TEXT
```